# Sign-in to Google account does nothing

Tags: google, samsung-galaxy-a5

I cannot add Google account to my Galaxy A5. I input email and password correctly, agree terms. Then the circle spins and nothing happens, account is not added. I cannot sign in to any Google stuff such as Gmail as well due to the same reason. I tried clearing cache of Google Play services but no help.

Comment: Which Android version is installed? Is the installed ROM the original or a custom ROM?

Comment: Version: 8.0.0. Should be original ROM if I understood correctly. I bought it from a shop 3 years ago. Google sign-in was working correctly but one day due to a forced update I guess it signed-out and now I cannot sign-in again.

Comment: You could try to manually update Google Play Services to a more recent version e.g using one of the variants that matches your device. Those APKs can be retrieved e.g. from ApkMirror: https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-21-33-13-release/

Comment: @alecxs I already did.

Comment: @alecxs I also cleared app data. No help.

Comment: @Robert I update Google Play services to 21.30.59 manually but problem still continues.